# How to return a value from a Scala def

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, but have some experience with Haskell. I did the following:

```
import scala.io.Source

val fileContent = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toList
val content = fileContent.map(processLine)

def processLine(line: String){
    val words = line.split("\\s+")
    println((words(0), words(1))) 
}
```

Here processLine doesn't return anything so content is now a list of empty return values for all items. I thought the solution would be to include a return value in processLine, but Scala doesn't like that:

```
warning: enclosing method processLine has result type Unit: return value discarded
```

So how can I modify processLine so that it can be used to create a list of non-empty tuple values in content? how would it be to declare a lambda function with more than one line?

Thanks to helpful info in this thread, I could also have written it with a lambda expression:

```
var nonLinearTrainingContent = fileContent.map(x=> {
        val words = x.split("\\s+")
        (words(0), words(2))
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that prevent a result being returned:

1. `println` returns `Unit`
2. Your function defintion is a shorthand for a method returning `Unit`

This would give you the result you expected:

```
def processLine(line: String) : (String,String) = {
  val words = line.split("\\s+")
  val result = (words(0), words(1))
  println(result)
  result
}
```

As asked the same expressed as a function:

```
val processLineFun : String => (String, String) = line => {
  val words = line.split("\\s+")
  val result = (words(0), words(1))
  println(result)
  result
}
```

Comment: andreas. Could you also please replace processLine with a lambda-function? I think that would complete/supplement the thread answer..

Answer (score 1):

Make the tuple (words(0), words(1)) the last line of processLine function:

```
def processLine(line: String) = {
  val words = line.split("\\s+")
  println((words(0), words(1))) 
  (words(0), words(1)) 
}
```

Edit: use curly braces for multiline lambda function or separate operators with ';' for one-line lambda

Edit2: fixed return type

Comment: This will still return `Unit`

Comment: there should be '=' before method body enclosed in curly braces, see my edit